# How does Solaris find man pages?

Tags: solaris, man

Initially, my MANPATH environment variable is not set.  Despite this, I can use the `man` command to view most man pages as usual.

`man top` can't find that particular man page, but `which man` tells me the command is in /opt/sfw/bin.

There are man pages for `top` and other commands in /opt/sfw/man.

I set `export MANPATH=/opt/sfw/man` and I can now see the man page with `man top`.  However `man` can no longer find pages for `bash`, `cp` or any other standard command.

How can I add this one directory to the list used to find man pages?

I'm using SunOS 5.10 and bash 3.0.16, if it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solaris 10's default `MANPATH` is `/usr/share/man`. You can add values to it:

```
MANPATH="/usr/share/man:/opt/sfw/man"
```

See the [man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9l1/index.html#Search%20Path) for more information.

[Solaris 11](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/man-1.html)'s default `MANPATH` is derived from `PATH`, so you wouldn't need to set the environment variable.

Comment: Thanks.  Just note that you then need to `export` MANPATH before it works.